# How to Grab data from database using JQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am attempting to create a menu that allows the user to click and drag the list items into a new order. The list data is pulled from a database.
I've managed to code the click and drag feature for my menu however, I am struggling to then save the data in the new order after the user has clicked and dragged.

This is my code for the sortable, it all works except for the line with var objmodel. When this variable is created it manages to grab an empty object from the database and populate the empty object with the new shuffle function value. What i need it to do is to grab the object that the user has clicked on to then populate that object with the new order.

Data Example:

1. cookie 
   2.biscuit
   3.chocolate.

after re order by user:

1.chocolate
2.biscuit
3.cookies

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MenuItem tbody').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = 1;
            var model = [];

            $("#MenuItem tbody tr").each(function () {
                var objModel = { id: $(this).find("#MenuItem").data("model"), ShuffleFunction: order };

                model.push(objModel);
                order++;
            });


        }
    });

});

  <table id = "MenuItem"  class="promo full-width alternate-rows" style="text-align: center;">  <!-- Cedric Kehi DEMO CHANGE -->




        <tr>
            <th>Product Code
            </th>
            <th>Product Template
            </th>
            @*<th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IndexList[0].Priority)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IndexList[0].WindowProduct)
            </th>*@
            <th>Description <!-- JACK EDIT -->
            </th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody >

        @foreach (var item in Model.IndexList)
        {


            <tr id ="trendingDisplay">

                <td class="center-text">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTemplate.Description)
                </td>
                @*<td class="center-text">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)
                </td>
                <td class="center-text">
                    @Html.Raw(item.WindowProduct ? "Yes" : "No")
                </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)

                </td>
```

@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { title = "Edit", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text edit" })
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { title = "Details", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text details" })
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { title = "Delete", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text delete" })

```
                </td>
            </tr>

        }


            </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the issue is here. You have not provided any example data or an example of the array at the end of `update`. Please edit your post and clarify it further.

Comment: refer to this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661264/able-to-save-jquery-sortable-new-order-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Comment: [Refer to this link for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661264/able-to-save-jquery-sortable-new-order-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Please Review: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

> **update( event, ui )**
>
> This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.
>
> **ui**
>
> - item
>
> Type: jQuery
>
> The jQuery object representing the current dragged element.

If you wish to make use of the item that the user grabbed and moved, you would use `ui.item`. From your example. This may look like:

```
var objModel = { id: ui.item.data("model"), ShuffleFunction: order };
```

Since you did not provide any HTML or working example of the items, I cannot confirm if this would work.

Comment: i have added the html and also a data example. ill try this code for  the time being

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959684/how-to-grab-data-from-database-using-jquery-sortable-and-post-data-back

Comment: If I answered this question, I would hope you would mark this answer. If it didn't, most people would Edit and Update their OP.