# How to Grab data from database using JQuery Sortable and post data back

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am attempting to create a menu that allows the user to re order the list items into a new order. The list data is pulled from a database. I've coded the jQuery sortable functionality feature for my menu however, I am struggling to then save the data in the new order back to model after the user has re ordered the list.

This is my code for the sortable, it all works except for the line with `var objmodel`. When this variable is created it manages to grab an empty object from the database and populate the empty object with the new shuffle function value (check link to image). What I need it to do is to grab the object that the user has clicked on to then populate that object with the new order.

I did use break point to with my method inside the controller and I noticed that it is picking up the data from the database but assigning the fields to null which generate a `NullReferenceException` error. Screen shot of the method is below:

[image]

Data Example:

1. cookie
2. biscuit
3. chocolate

And after re-order by user:

1. chocolate
2. biscuit
3. cookies

I have been struggling with this matter and will do with a solution if anyone can help?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MenuItem tbody').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.context.id);
            var order = 1;
            var model = [];
            // var sortedIDs = $("#MenuItem tbody").sortable("serialize");
            //alert(sortedIDs);
            //alert(objModel);

            //$.getJSON('ProductsList', { ID: objModel }, function (result) {

            $("#MenuItem tbody tr").each(function () {

                var objModel = { Id: ui.item.data("model"), ShuffleFunction: order }; //This is for example to build your object and push in a modal array.

                //building a new object and pushing in modal array 
                //Here I am setting OrderNo property which is i am using in my db and building my object
                model.push(objModel);
                     order++;
                    //alert(result);
                //});
            });

           if (model.length > 1) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("MoveFunction", "Product")', //This is my url put your url here and pass model as data it is an array of my items
                    data: JSON.stringify({ model: model }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        //do something
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        //do something
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

});

 <table id = "MenuItem"  class="promo full-width alternate-rows" style="text-align: center;">  <!-- Cedric Kehi DEMO CHANGE -->




        <tr>
            <th>Product Code
            </th>
            <th>Product Template
            </th>
            @*<th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IndexList[0].Priority)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IndexList[0].WindowProduct)
            </th>*@
            <th>Description <!-- JACK EDIT -->
            </th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody >


        @foreach (var item in Model.IndexList)
        {




            <tr id ="trendingDisplay">

                <td class="center-text">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTemplate.Description)
                </td>
                @*<td class="center-text">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)
                </td>
                <td class="center-text">
                    @Html.Raw(item.WindowProduct ? "Yes" : "No")
                </td>*@
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)

                </td>



            </tr>



        }


            </tbody>

    </table>

 [HttpPost]
    // This Code Needs Fixing 
    public void MoveFunction(List<Product> model)
    {

        int id = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"];
        int customerid = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomerID"];
        int promotionid = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["PromotionID"];

        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
        productList = ProductLogic.GetBy(x => x.PromotionID == promotionid && x.Active == true);
        int i = 1;

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var status = ProductLogic.GetBy(x => x.ProductID == item.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (status != null)
            {
                status.ShuffleFunction = item.ShuffleFunction;
            }
            ProductLogic.Update(status);
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Created a Working example for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/45dw9fve/ First issue I have found, `ui.item.context` is not defined. What is this object 'sposed to be?

Comment: Second, you call `Id: ui.item.data("model")`, yet there are no data attributes on your `tr` elements, which would be the `ui.item` in this scenario. But you're doing this inside of a ForEach loop, so it's being re-written each time. I suspect you wanted to iterate each row, collecting the new order and associated models.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the following line:

```
alert(ui.item.context.id);
```

I think you meant:

```
alert(ui.item.attr("id"));
```

Or maybe:

```
alert(ui.item[0].context.id);
```

Regardless, it was causing an issue in my testing. Next I had to look at your loop and determine what information you were trying to use after the sort. Since each sort item was a row, I could not find a `data-model` attribute for the rows; hence, I added one.Consider if this was the resulting HTML from your .NET Script. Since that's what your jQuery will be working with, it's not worth using .NET script in your example, but some type of example output.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/45dw9fve/3/

**HTML**

```
<table id="MenuItem" class="promo full-width alternate-rows" style="text-align: center;">
  <!-- Cedric Kehi DEMO CHANGE -->
  <tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Product Template</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
    <th>Window Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="trendingDisplay" data-model="model-1">
      <td class="center-text">0001</td>
      <td>Template 1</td>
      <td class="center-text">1</td>
      <td class="center-text">Yes</td>
      <td>Description 1</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trendingDisplay" data-model="model-2">
      <td class="center-text">0020</td>
      <td>Template 1</td>
      <td class="center-text">5</td>
      <td class="center-text">Yes</td>
      <td>Description 2</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trendingDisplay" data-model="model-3">
      <td class="center-text">0300</td>
      <td>Template 3</td>
      <td class="center-text">1</td>
      <td class="center-text">No</td>
      <td>Description 3</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trendingDisplay" data-model="model-4">
      <td class="center-text">4000</td>
      <td>Template 4</td>
      <td class="center-text">1</td>
      <td class="center-text">Yes</td>
      <td>Description 4</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your .NET Script will populate the table, you may need to adjust it's loop to place the `data-model` attribute into each row.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#MenuItem tbody').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      //alert(ui.item.context.id);
      var order = 1;
      var model = [];

      $("#MenuItem tbody tr").each(function(key, elem) {
        model.push({
          id: $(elem).data("model"),
          ShuffleFunction: order
        });
        order++;
      });
      console.log(model);

      if (model.length > 1) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          //url: '@Url.Action("MoveFunction", "Product")', //This is my url put your url here and pass model as data it is an array of my items
          url: '/echo/json/',
          data: {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                model: model
              })
            },
          success: function(data) {
            //do something
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(e) {
            //do something
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

For the jsfiddle example, I used their `/echo/json/` url, which just echos the data from `json` back to `data` in this case.

When you move an item, sorting it, you can then open the console and review the model array. If you have questions, comment.

Comment: You hard coded your example where as my data example above is pulled from the database. What i am now trying to do is to edit these data and post it pack to the database. I checked the console and it brings up the array with IDs however they are all null rather than the db data.

Comment: @cazlouise please edit your post and include a sample of the Source HTML that is presented by your ASP.NET Script. JavaScript is a Client side scripting language, so it's working with the resulting HTML that is sent back from the server. This is why my example is "hard coded" as you put it. It's a guess at what your resulting HTML may have looked like.

Comment: the source html that is is presented by my ASP.NET script in embedded inside the table in my html

Comment: Yes, can you add some of that to your post?